# Como asiganar semana numero uno

Tags: sql, sql-server

Que tal amigos me gustaria saber como puedo asigar la semana numero uno empezando desde el 26 de diciembre al 1 de enero y por consiguiente la semana numero 2 del 2 de enero al 8 de enero.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Tengo este codigo pero me da las semanas desde el 1 de enero al 8 de enero como semana numero 1:

```
SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,dtmFecha) AS intSemana, dtmFecha  
FROM RegistroAnual
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías intentar con la siguiente query:

```sql
SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATEADD(day, -6, dtmFecha)) AS intSemana, dtmFecha FROM RegistroAnual
```

Usando la función DATEADD para restar 6 días a la fecha dada, con esto el 26 de diciembre se tomaría como el día 1 y se inicia el conteo de las semanas a partir de ese dia. Espero que te sirva, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Eso creería (no tengo pruebas, tampoco dudas) que parte de la configuración regional, donde el primer día de la semana es el domingo, etc.

Para que no sea así y el primer día de la semana sea, digamos, el lunes, debes usar [DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SET DATEFIRST { number | @number_var }
```

Y el parámetro va de 1 a 7, donde 1 es Lunes, 2 es Martes, etc.

Prueba cambiando ese parámetro y corriendo de nuevo tu consulta.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 ;
SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,dtmFecha) AS intSemana, dtmFecha  
FROM RegistroAnual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta forma

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(week, dtmFecha) - DATEPART(week, '2019-12-26') + 1 AS intSemana,
    dtmFecha
FROM RegistroAnual
```

Comment: Con una explicación en la respuesta no vendría mal...